# What is the syntax for calling a function defined seperately on an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My query is a bit trivial but I am not sure if I am doing everything correctly.

I am trying to call a function when a checkbox is clicked.

```
window.onload = function(){
$("#checkboxid").click(myfunction());
}

function myfunction (){
//Code here
}
```

The myfunction function isn't called upon clicking the checbox and I have checked in the browser debugger as well that it's not being called. Can anyone please help in pointing out why?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `()` from where you call `myfunction`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $("#checkboxid").click(myfunction);
}

function myfunction() {
  console.log('here')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxid" label="Click Me">
```